# Android Touchevent - Pinch gesture

Tags: android

I was looking at the `ScaleGestureDetector` class. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html

I have two method's which does the `Zoom-In and ZoomOut`. Which method should i over-ride to call these two methods.

```
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {@
    Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        return true;
    }

    Override
    public boolean  onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        return true;
    }

    Override
    public boolean  onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

    }
}
```

Let's take when i do a pinch-up, i want to call `Zoom-In` and pinch-down i want to call `Zoom-out`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get scale factor by calling [ScaleGestureDetecteor.getScaleFactor()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html#getScaleFactor%28%29) inside of `onScale` method. If it is less than one, you are zooming out, otherwise - zooming in